# Tabs displayed differently depending on if Theme.NoTitleBar is set or not in the manifest

Tags: android, tabs, icons

The tabs are displayed differently depending on if Theme.NoTitleBar is set or not in the manifest. I want the no title bar look when I have a title bar. Any idéa how to achieve that?

I have two images that illustrates the problem.

When NoTitleBar is specified in the manifest the tabs are displayed with icons and text. When NoTitleBar is not specified (and I get a title bar in the app) only text is displayed on the tabs.

[image: NoTitleBar set in manifest - tabs without image]

[image: NoTitleBar NOT set in manifest - tabs with image]

Comment: I have voted up the question. Try adding images in some time

Comment: Thanks for voting up the question guys. Now I was able to attach the images. I hope this makes the question clear :)

Comment: I think I just might have to live with that look. I guess that it is the theme that make the tabs look like that and when I change to the NoTitleBar theme the tabs in that theme looks better (to me anyway :)

Comment: I have not worked with themes/ styles ,so I can't help at this time. Maybe I will put up a bounty on this question tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

That is **Theme.Holo**, my friend. Try to using **Theme.Holo** or **Theme.Holo.NoActionBar** or **Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen** or whatever you want with **Theme.Holo**. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

if you want the original style of your Ui to remain and the title bar to be removed with no effect on that, you have to remove the title bar in your activity's code rather than the manifest. leave the original theme style that you had in the manifest and in each activity that you want no title bar use `this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` in the `oncreate()` method before `setcontentview()` like below:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
    ...
    }
```